# Can I use the values from a form in other form with Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app with two forms where the views.py looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from pbmcalculator.models import PbmCalculator, simulator
from django.core.cache import cache   
import json

@login_required
 

def subs_calc(request):
    
    # this is from the first form #

    selection = request.GET.get("id", None)
    customer = request.GET.get("customer", None)
    initial_date = request.GET.get("initial_date", None)
    final_date = request.GET.get("final_date", None)
    

    if selection is not None and 'initial_date' in request.GET:
        calculation_target = PbmCalculator(customer, initial_date, final_date)
        html = TemplateResponse(
            request,
            "pbmcalculator/table.html",
            {
                some operations
            },
            )
        
        return html 
    
   
    if 'generico_sim' in request.GET:
        
        # this is from the second form #

        brand_sim = request.GET.get("brand_sim",None)
        generico_sim = request.GET.get("generico_sim",None)
        marca_sim = request.GET.get("marca_sim",None)
        initial_date_sim = '2021-08-08'
        final_date_sim = '2021-08-15'        

        calculation_sim = simulator(brand_sim, initial_date_sim, final_date_sim)
        html = TemplateResponse(
            request,
            "pbmcalculator/table1.html",
            {
               some operations
            },
            )
        return html

    return render(request, "pbmcalculator/subs_calc.html", {"selected": False})
```

So I want to use the variables **initial_date** and **final_date** in the second if statement to fill the **initial_date_sim** and **final_date_sim**. I tried several ways but none worked. Some idea?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why it did not work i.e. did you not get the desired output? did you receive an error?

Comment: Also, consider using [django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/). This massively cleans your code up and is an easier way to work with forms.

Comment: Thank you Jelle for asking me. Actually, I want to use both initial_date and final_date instead of '2021-08-08' and '2021-08-15' in the second if statement respectively, but when I print this variable before the if statement I can see that the result is none and consequently the SQL fails.

Comment: If you tried `initial_date_sim = initial_date` and it gave you `None`, then your problem is most likely somewhere else. For example, you are using `method='POST'` in your form and using `GET` in your backend/you made a typo in the names of the form fields/something else. If you want us to know we need to see at least the html form and maybe also the snippet of the `urls.py` where the redirection happens.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by taking the values through the ajax of each form, there it doesn't matter if the value comes from one or the other. then the second form will be filtered by the dates of the first as I wanted. Thank you Jelle for your time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).